# Generating hierarchal URL from hierarchal data

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a decision tree based on [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/decision-tree-select.html) jQuery plugin.
It expects data in this format:

```
$tree = array(
    "href" => "/",
    "label" => "Title",
    "nodes" => array(
        array(
            "href" => "/q1",
            "label" => "Question 1?",
            "nodes" => array(
                array(
                    "href" => "/q1/a1",
                    "label" => "Answer 1",
                    "nodes" => array(
                        "href" => "/q1/a1/q11",
                        "label" => "Question 1.1?",
                        "nodes" => array(
                            array(
                                "href" => "/q1/a1/q11/a11",
                                "label" => "Answer 1.1",
                                "nodes" => null
                            ),
                            array(
                                "href" => "/q1/a1/q11/a12",
                                "label" => "Answer 1.1",
                                "nodes" => null
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    "href" => "/q1/a2",
                    "label" => "Answer 2",
                    "nodes" => null
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I fetch the results as a flat list from a database and then am able to generate the tree structure using a recursive function:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $rootId = 0, $current_path = '', $new_path = '') {
    $ctr = 0;
    $branch = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['root_id'] == $rootId) {
            $array = array(
                'root_id' => $element['root_id'],
                'label' => $element['label'],
                'text' => $element['text'],
            );
            if(!empty($current_path)){
                $path = $current_path . ++$ctr;
                $array['href'] = $path;
            }
            $new_path = $new_path == '/q' ? '/a' : '/q';
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id'], $path . $new_path, $new_path);
            if ($children) {
                $array['nodes'] = $children;
            } 
            $branch[] = $array;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($results);
```

which yields:

```
$tree = array(
    "href" => "/",
    "label" => "Title",
    "nodes" => array(
        array(
            "href" => "/q1",
            "label" => "Question 1?",
            "nodes" => array(
                array(
                    "href" => "/q1/a1",
                    "label" => "Answer 1",
                    "nodes" => array(
                        "href" => "/q1/a1/q1",
                        "label" => "Question 1.1?",
                        "nodes" => array(
                            array(
                                "href" => "/q1/a1/q1/a1",
                                "label" => "Answer 1.1",
                                "nodes" => null
                            ),
                            array(
                                "href" => "/q1/a1/q1/a1",
                                "label" => "Answer 1.1",
                                "nodes" => null
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    "href" => "/q1/a2",
                    "label" => "Answer 2",
                    "nodes" => null
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which gives the correct 'href's up to a depth of 2 but then deviates from the expected format.
I can't figure out how to get the 'href's correct.

How can i generate the correct 'href' using my recursive function as expected by the jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = $current_path . ++$ctr;
```

You're counting yet this value is localized for that particular function even on recursion. It will never and seems to never move above 1 because after it iterates once, it calls buildTree again.

Is q11 not stored in the database? You need a way of incrementing/parsing/gathering (i am not sure exactly what the value should be) that value to what it should be as it recurses through.  Should this value just remove the **.**  from **1.1** ?

Try dropping in this function in place of yours and see if it changes anything:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $rootId = 0, $current_path = '', $new_path = '', $parent_id = 0, $ctr = 0) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['root_id'] == $rootId) {
            $array = array(
                'root_id' => $element['root_id'],
                'label' => $element['label'],
                'text' => $element['text'],
            );
            if(!empty($current_path)){
                if($parent_id > 0 ) {
                    $path = $current_path . $parent_id . $ctr;
                }else{
                    $path = $current_path . ++$ctr;
                }
                $array['href'] = $path;
            }
            $new_path = $new_path == '/q' ? '/a' : '/q';
            $parent_id++;
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id'], $path . $new_path, $new_path, $parent_id, $ctr);
            $parent_id--;
            if ($children) {
                $array['nodes'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $array;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```